# Wordpress update change my nav to default

Tags: wordpress

I make a website on Wordpress.
 I change the nav-template because I need to insert my own classes to li and ul elements.
 I did it and the nav was looking that like I need it.
 When I update WP today, nav was back to default.
 How to do make it better that I don't have to change it on every update? I edited wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php near 110 line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I edited wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php near 110 line....

Never edit WordPress core files. Never. Because this is what happens when WordPress is updated: you lose your changes.

Never edit files such as `nav-menu-template.php` in core; make menu modifications - be them CSS, PHP or HTML - in the *theme*. That's how WordPress works: there are core files - `wp-includes, wp-admin`, etc - that create the admin area and handle all the backend stuff. And there are theme files, in the working theme, located in `wp-content/themes/whatever-theme-you-are-using/` that create the front end that the user sees.

These two parts create a WordPress site. Never edit core; https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files You *can* edit a theme. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/what-is-a-theme/

(You can also modify core and theme functions with plugins, too.)

Beyond that, when working with themes, first make a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) before you edit the full copy of a theme.